# Android Management API with EMM Community

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-sites, android-management-api, android-managed-profile

I'm using `Android Management API` to create `Work Profile`. Usage limit to this is per project 1000 devices and 1000 queries per 100 seconds for each project. I want to increase this limit also I want to explore `DPC Support Library`, that's not publicly available.

I've already filled up the `EMM Community form` from [here](https://www.cloudconnect.goog/docs/DOC-13121) and only received acknowledgment mail in return. Which says I'll receive NDA and further communication will be mailed. It's been more than 2 weeks but no other reply or mail is received.

And on [library link](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/build-dpc) I still receive this error

*We’re sorry...
...but it looks like you don’t have access to this place or content. If you think you should have access to this space, try logging out and back in again using your account menu accessible by clicking your avatar in the top right corner of this page. If this issue persists, please notify your Support Representative and we will troubleshoot further.*

Can someone help me solve this error or is there any other way to get the access to this EMM Community?

Comment: Hi Did you got the approval for community ? and is there any pricing attached to it?

Comment: @Ankur check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all the followup mails, I decided to use `Android Management API` with default quota for now. Here's the summary of replies received over email from `EMM Community` about quota and joining:

> Our services is completely free but EMMs need be implement all
>   mandatory features and approved by us upon signing the legal
>   agreements within 180 days for at least one solution set (Work
>   profile, Fully managed device, Dedicated device or MAM) before they
>   can use it on production with customers.
>
> The EMM community resources and support are only for commercial EMM
>   vendors, as they need to implement the mandatory features required for
>   one solution set(requirements typically update every year), failure to
>   integrate a solution set within 180 days or comply with the subsequent
>   requirements update could result in revoke of their API.
>
> For the default usage limits, now the API provides unlimited
>   enterprises with 1000 devices each. We'd suggest to continue using the
>   API without joining the community that we'll be notified when you are
>   reaching 1000 devices for a quota increase as long as you are not
>   providing EMM services to other enterprise customers.

And this is what they said about `DPC Support Library` library:

> ‘DPC Support Library’ is a helper library doesn't apply to Android
>   Management API as it's only used by Play EMM API developers who have
>   to build a custom DPC app.

Comment: Thanks ! So now your solution is creating multiple  enterprises for every 1000 devices ?

Comment: Once the limit is reached will try to contact the community again for quota increase or create multiple enterprises every 1000 devices.

Comment: @sneharc as per above answer I can understand there is no cost for using Android management API right? also I can able to enroll 1000 device per enterprise right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the DPC Support Library if you're using the Android Management API.

If you need to increase your quota above the default quota, just join the EMM Community and ask for your quota to be lifted. This does not require changing your implementation or using a new library.

But note that the default quota (1,000 devices and 1,000 requests per 100 seconds) is already quite high and should be more than enough for most deployments.

Comment: I'm creating this app for enterprise organisation where employee strength is 5000+, so need to increase this quota and for joining EMM community there's one form filling which I've done already. Now awaiting reply :(